Cross-correlation function using Spearman's correlation
Is it "kosher" to use Spearman's correlation in place of Pearson's in the cross-correlation function?
Basically, I have used the cross-correlation function to determine correlation over a lag. for two time series. After reviewing my results, due to the nature of my data, I think Spearman's distributed over a lag could be a better choice, but I'm not sure if this is "kosher" to do.
Any thoughts?

Sure you can, that's why it's a cross correlation function.

How would you use the results?  They might be informative in a descriptive or exploratory sense, but likely unhelpful for standard uses such as identifying time series models or estimating their parameters.

@whuber -- descriptive or exploratory sense. but ultimately, for each time series i'm computing, i'd want to tax the max correlation for each pair and average them. this should be ok, right?

I do not understand what you mean by "tax" nor what a "max correlation" for a pair (of what?) would be.
